# Jasmine spyOn on function and returned object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, meteor, jasmine, angular-mock

I'm using MeteorJS with angular and want to test controller. My controller use $reactive(this).attach($scope). I need to check, if this method was called.

I create something like that for spy:

```
var $reactive = function(ctrl) {
    return {
        attach:function(scope) {}
    }
};
```

So I can call it like that:

```
$reactive('aaa').attach('bbb');
```

How I can do it in tests?

```
spyOn($reactive, 'attach');
```

Doesn't work. I got **Error: attach() method does not exist**

And how to check if it was called?
This is good call?

```
expect($reactive).toHaveBeenCalledWith(controller);
```

And how to check that function attach was called with args (scope)?

Comment: Looks like `$reactive` returns an object that contains the attach method, right? And you want to test this `attach` method to have been called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to mock the `$reactive` component. Replace it with a spy that returns an `spyObj` in the scope of the test. Then trigger what ever makes the `$reactive` method to run and test.

```
var reactiveResult = jasmine.createSpyObj('reactiveResult', ['attach']);
var $reactive = jasmine.createSpy('$reactive').and.returnValue(reactiveResult);
var controller = {};
    beforeEach(function () {
      module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory('$reactive', $reactive);
      });
      module('yourAppModule');
    });

it('Should call attach', function () {
  $reactive(controller).attach();
  expect($reactive).toHaveBeenCalledWith(controller);
  expect(reactiveResult.attach).toHaveBeenCalled();
}) ;
```

You can provide the `$reactive` spy to the controller dependencies too:

```
var reactiveResult = jasmine.createSpyObj('reactiveResult', ['attach']);
var $reactive = jasmine.createSpy('$reactive').and.returnValue(reactiveResult);
var ctrl;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
      ctrl = $controller('YourController', {$reactive: $reactive });
    }));

it('Should call attach', function () {
  //ctrl.triggerThe$reactiveCall
  expect($reactive).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctrl);
  expect(reactiveResult.attach).toHaveBeenCalled();
}) ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I know something more about tests.